# Execute multiple Stored Procedures with Quartz.NET

Tags: sql-server, quartz.net

Still trying to wrap my head around Quartz.NET after reading all the tutorials, which seem very code specific, versus implementation focused. Here's what I'm trying to do. I have 20 SQL stored procs that do various things, like query log tables, resubmit data to other processes, etc. I'd like to have these SP running throughout the day at regular intervals. So it seems like a natural for Quartz.NET.  I plan on creating a Windows Svc that implements Quartz.NET and contains jobs in assemblies in the same folder as the Quartz assembly.

One bad way to implement this, I think, would be to write a single job class for every SP and associate a separate trigger for each one. The job class would simply execute a particular SP whose named was hard coded in the class. That's the bad way.

But for the life of me I can't figure out what the Good way would be. Obviously having a single job class that just does a generic 'execute SP by name', where the names come from a simple SQL table, seems like the way to go, but how would I get different triggers associated with different SPs, and how would Quartz know to load up all twenty SPs on separate threads?

And how would Quartz know to pickup a changed trigger for example for one of the SPs? Would that have to be a start/stop cycle on the Win Svc to reload jobs and triggers, or would I have to hand code some kind of "reload" too?

Any thoughts? Am I misunderstanding what Quartz is? The verbiage makes it sound like it's an Enterprise Scheduler, a System, a thing you install. All the documentation OTOH makes it seem like just a bunch of classes you stitch together to create your OWN scheduler or scheduling system, no different from the classes MS provides in .NET to create apps that do FTP for example. Maybe I'm expecting too much?

Comment: //The verbiage makes it sound like it's an Enterprise Scheduler, a System, a thing you install. All the documentation OTOH makes it seem like just a bunch of classes you stitch together //   That's exactly where I am with it..............

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pretty easy way to fulfill your requirements could be:

**Start with sample server**

Take Quartz.NET distribution's server as starting point, you have there a ready made template for a Windows service that utilizes TopShelf for easy installation

**Use XML configuration with change detection**

quartz.config file contains the actual configuration, there you can see that jobs and triggers are read from XML file quartz_jobs.xml .

You need to add *quartz.plugin.xml.scanInterval = 10* to watch for changes (every ten seconds)

**Use trigger job data maps to parameterize the job**

You can use same job class for every trigger if SQL execution is as trivial as you propose. Just add needed configuration to trigger's definition in XML (sample here that runs every ten seconds, add as many triggers as you want):

```
<trigger>
  <simple>
    <name>sqlTrigger1</name>
    <job-name>genericSqlJob</job-name>
    <job-group>sqlJobs</job-group>
    <job-data-map>
      <entry>
        <key>sql_to_run</key>
        <value>select 1</value>
      </entry>
    </job-data-map>
    <misfire-instruction>SmartPolicy</misfire-instruction>
    <repeat-count>-1</repeat-count>
    <repeat-interval>10000</repeat-interval>
  </simple>
</trigger>
```

Just use the quartz_jobs.xml as base and make required changes.

**Use configuration in your job**

You can access the configuration in your job from context's MergedJobDataMap that contains both job's and trigger's parameters, latter overriding former.

```
public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
{
    string sqlToRun = context.MergedJobDataMap.GetString("sql_to_run");
    SqlTemplate.ExecuteSql(sqlToRun);
}
```